# An adjective for annoying

Tags: adjectives

Often I see people write urusai to mean annoying, and I've also seen meiwaku, but I was wondering if there was an adjective closer to meaning annoying. Mendokusai means bothersome, but in a different sense, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a bunch of words which can mean "annoying" or something related:

- `めんどくさい` (also `めんどい`): something that requires effort but you don't feel like doing or dislike doing for whatever reason; bothersome
- `うるさい`: lit. "noisy" or "loud"; can also be used to refer to annoying people, their words or actions
- `むかつく`: something or someone who raises your blood pressure, ticks you off
- `イライラする`: to get annoyed by something/someone
- `しつこい(奴{やつ})`: obstinate or insistent (person) who is pestering you with silly questions etc.
- `腹{はら}が立{た}つ`: to get angry/furious/pissed off
- `邪魔{じゃま}な(もの)`: something/someone who's a hindrance, in your way literally or figuratively.
- `うざい` (often said as `うぜえ`): can mean many things: annoying, bothersome, gross, nuisance etc. Used mostly by young people; apparently very offensive to the point of [leading to bloodshed or suicides](http://zokugo-dict.com/03u/uzai.htm).

Other words from dictionaries which I haven't encountered myself so not certain of their nuances.

- `うっとうしい`
- `じれったい`
- `わずらわしい`
- `しゃくに[障]{さわ}る`

Answer (score -1):

`詰らない` (adjective in i) means annoying, boring or not interesting.

Comment: For me "annoying" suggests some level of being agitated. 詰まらない means just the opposite: dull/uninteresting/pointless/... I don't it is a good synonym for annoying.

Comment: ふしぎの海のナディア, マリー　in one episode she said つまんな〜い and she is referring about the annoying situation. [image](http://livedoor.blogimg.jp/peperon999/imgs/3/1/310f7987.jpg) or so i have understand, maybe i'm wrong...

Comment: I guess that annoyed people often say つまらない/つまんない (in the sense of "that's lame"), but that doesn't mean that つまらない actually means "annoying".

Comment: I always thought マリー was using つまんない to mean something closer to "boring".

Comment: annoying is not synonyms of boring ? [annoying synonyms](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/annoying)

Comment: Almost of the words in that list have different meanings.  I think they're listed in the thesaurus because they're *similar*, not because they're *identical*.  Personally, I agree with Earthling's comment that "annoying" suggests some level of being agitated, while "boring" suggests the opposite.